# Netbeans 8 - How to change the default variable filter when debugging (used for PHP)

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans

I am using Netbeans to debug PHP. When I stop at a breakpoint it shows the variables I want to see (via xdebug), except some.

To see the rest I have to right+click in the variable list area, click on "Filters..." and then check the ones I want to see, in this case "NULL type".

What I would like to to do is change the default so I don't have to enable looking at "NULL type" each time I start debugging ("Uninitialized" is the other option but I'm going to leave unchecked for now).

Does anyone know how to do this?